# Nullpointer Exception in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am very new to java. I was trying to take input from a file, and set the arguments from the file as hashmap key and value. But it returns null pointer exception on the line where i am splitting the arguments from line. This is my code :

```
public class hashtable{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        HashMap nodes = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String filename = args[0];
        FileReader file = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try{
          file = new FileReader(filename);
          reader = new BufferedReader(file);
          String line;
          line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
             line = reader.readLine();
             String []arguments = line.split("\\s+");
             nodes.put(arguments[2],arguments[1]);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){}
        finally{
          reader.close();
        } 

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5;i++){
            System.out.println(nodes.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

where am i going wrong ? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JoeC no it is not. Please read the question.

Comment: I have read the question.  I see no reason to believe that this is not a duplicate.  If you show me why the answer to that question does not answer yours, then we can discuss further.

Comment: For starters, you would need to include the stack trace that shows *the exact place* where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if line 1 is not null, but then you proceed to read and use line 2 instead. Move the next `readLine()` to the end of the loop:

```
line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null){
    String []arguments = line.split("\\s+");
    nodes.put(arguments[2],arguments[1]);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Or, more conventionally, you can merge both `readLine()` statements into the loop condition:

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

Comment: ah that was stupid of me. 
Thanks a lot